# c string and file operations

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to setup a local folder access from a c program by first initializing a string to the location the subsequently reading files from there. I'll also be required to write files in a similar manner eventually, but I am getting some strange bugs.

first the code:
resource_utils.h

```
static char* res_dir = NULL;

void clearnUpResourcePath(void);
char* getResource(char* filename);
char* readFile(char* file_path);
void writeFile(filename, File* file);
```

resource_utils.c

```
#include "resource_utils.h"

static char* getBasePath(void);
static void initResourcePath(void);

char* getResource(char* filename)
{
    if(res_dir == NULL)
    {
        initResourcePath();
    }
        printf("res dir: %s || fn:%s\n",res_dir, filename);
        char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) + strlen(res_dir) + strlen(filename));
        memcpy(str, res_dir, strlen(res_dir)+1);
        memcpy(str + strlen(res_dir), filename, strlen(filename));
        str[(strlen(filename) + strlen(res_dir))] = '\0';
        printf("resource filename:%s\n\n",str);
        return str;
}

static void initResourcePath(void) {
    char *base_path = getBasePath();

    size_t len = strlen(base_path) + 22;
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t sz = 0;
    char tmp[len];
    while(base_path[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(base_path[i] == 'b' && base_path[i+1] == 'i' && base_path[i+2] == 'n')
        {
            sz = i;
        }
        tmp[i] = base_path[i];
        i++;
    }
    char* b = strstr(tmp, "/bin");
    memcpy(b, "/bin/resources/",15);
    tmp[ sz + 14 ] = '\0';

    res_dir = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (sz + 4));
    i = 0;
    while(tmp[i] != '\0')
    {
        res_dir[i] = tmp[i];
        i++;
    }
    res_dir[i] = '\0';

    free(base_path);

}

void clearnUpResourcePath(void)
{
    free(res_dir);
}

static char* getBasePath(void)
{
    return "string to working directory"
}

char* readFile(char* file_path)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(file_path, "r");
    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        printf("failed to open file path:%s\n",file_path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size_t size = 1024;
    char ch;
    int index = 0;
    char* line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    while( (ch = (char)fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
    {
        *(line+index) = ch;
        ++index;
        if(index == size-1)
        {
            size = size * 2;
            line = realloc(line, size);
            printf("\nreallocing %zu\n",size);
        }
        line = realloc(line, (sizeof(char) * index) + 1);
        *(line+index) = '\0';
    }
    //printf("sanity check\n\n%d\n\n",strlen(line));
    //printf("final size: %lu for loading: %s\n",strlen(line), file_path);
    fclose(fp);
    return line;
}
```

This is basically suppose to setup this resource path once, keep it around for the lifetime of the program and free it before the program exits, but I get some strange results sometimes.

Take a look at this output

```
    char* vshad = getResource("vert.shad");
    char* fshad = getResource("frag.shad");
    char* name = getResource("pal.ppm");
    char* name1 = getResource("1234pal.ppm");
    char* name2 = getResource("pal.ppm1234");
    char* name3 = getResource("pal1.ppm");
    char* name4 = getResource("pal.pp");
    char* name5 = getResource("pal.ppdddddm");
    char* name6 = getResource("pa");

res dir: /Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/ || fn:vert.shad
res dir len:48, filename len:9
resource filename:/Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/vert.shad

res dir: /Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/ || fn:frag.shad
res dir len:48, filename len:9
resource filename:/Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/frag.shad

res dir: /Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYS || fn:pal.ppm
res dir len:57, filename len:7
resource filename:/Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYSpal.ppm

res dir: /Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYS || fn:1234pal.ppm
res dir len:57, filename len:11
resource filename:/Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYS1234pal.ppm

res dir: /Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYS || fn:pal.ppm1234
res dir len:57, filename len:11
resource filename:/Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYSpal.ppm1234

res dir: /Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYS || fn:pal1.ppm
res dir len:57, filename len:8
resource filename:/Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYSpal1.ppm

res dir: /Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYS || fn:pal.pp
res dir len:57, filename len:6
resource filename:/Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYSpal.pp

res dir: /Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYS || fn:pal.ppdddddm
res dir len:57, filename len:12
resource filename:/Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYSpal.ppdddddm

res dir: /Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYS || fn:pa
res dir len:57, filename len:2
resource filename:/Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYSpa

loaded name:/Users/username/DIRECTORY/project/build/bin/resources/FACETKEYSpal.ppm?
```

the first two calls load properly but subsequent calls, especially if i change the length of the filename causes the code to break. I am not really sure.

I also noticed that the length of my res_dir changes which I really don't understand.

**along with the accepted answer, here is my new code w/o magic numbers**

```
static void initResourcePath(void)
{
    char *base_path = getBasePath();

    size_t len = strlen(base_path) *2; //making enough space
    size_t i, sz = 0;
    char tmp[len];
    while(base_path[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(base_path[i] == 'b' && base_path[i+1] == 'i' && base_path[i+2] == 'n')
        {
            sz = i;
        }
        tmp[i] = base_path[i];
        i++;
    }
    char* b = strstr(tmp, "/bin");
    memcpy(b, "/bin/resources/",15);
    tmp[ sz + 14 ] = '\0';
    res_dir = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tmp) +1));
    strcpy(res_dir, tmp);
    free(base_path);
}
```

Comment: sometimes i don't get SO... You ask a question and it get down voted w/o even a single comment. What is the deal w/ that?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect that the downvoter would like to see a minimal description of the problem. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: note: I didn't dv this. Out of curiosity, `static char* res_dir = NULL;` in your **header** file ? That has no earthly reason for being in the header, and several for why it should be declared *inside* resource_utils.c *only*. Beyond that, your code is quite-literally *loaded* with magic numbers, any one of which may be contributing to the root problem. This deserves a thorough wash through valgrind. Btw. I hope your *real* `getBasePath` does more than return a string literal. That `free(base_path)` is counting on dynamic allocation, and invokes UB without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is here:

```
res_dir = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (sz + 4));
```

You're not allocating enough space.  You probably meant to use `sz + 14` instead of `sz + 4`.  That's one of the issues with using magic numbers as WhozCraig mentioned.

Rather than doing something convoluted like that, you know that you're copying `tmp` into `res_dir`, so do this instead:

```
res_dir = malloc(strlen(tmp)+1);
```

Note that the return value of `malloc` is not being casted.  Doing so in C can hide subtle bugs if you fail to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: thank you and I actually cleaned up a lot of the code by using strcpy. I'll add that to the question.